# BoT to generate a new sales lead in say CRM

Tags: botframework

we want to build BoT which we want to use this as a marketing agent. Planning to host this BoT as a web chat or Facebook channel BoT using which user can get more information on the products. Once a user is checking new products then we want to generate a lead in CRM with certain user details?

Do you guys think this is possible? Any sample application built.

Comment: Yes. where is the complexity? Please explain more the problem.

Comment: Say we want to generate a lead in CRM we are assuming we might need certain user details. So how can we get this done? also any idea on what level of user details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

more detail would be needed to answer your question more completely.

*Depending on what channels you use you can get user information from the channel such as user ID or name. this information may be able to be used to connect with the user via that channel.
*You could also explicitly ask the user for information.
*it is entirely possible to do this.